# XSD: How to validate the XML file according to value of some tag?

Tags: xml, schema, xsd

I was trying to validate this XML file ...
 where if

1. `<tag1>` is "Y" then `<tag2>` must appear
2. if `<tag1>` is "N" then `<tag2>` must not appear ..

   ```
   <parent>
     <a>
       <tag1>Y</tag1>
       <tag2>sometext</tag2>
     </a>
     <a>
       <tag1>N</tag1>
     </a>
   </parent>
   ```

I tried `<choice>` tag but doesn't seem to work .. :( I have come to conclusion that this feature is not available in XSD ..

Can you guide me atleast some alternative to implement this ? by the way I am using Visual Studio 2005 ..

Comment: What XML parser are you using for validation?

Comment: I don't know much about it ..
i have to use visual studio 2005 .. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known fact that this is a handycap of XML schema. But I would appreciate your approach of trying the `<choice>` tag. It could be successful if your conditions were something like this:

1. If `<tag1>` is required and appears first then `<tag2>` isn't required (and appears as second tag)
2. If `<tag2>` is required and appears first then `<tag1>` isn't required (and appears as second)

The code is:

```
<xs:element name="parent">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="a" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="tag1" type="xs:boolean" />
              <xs:element name="tag2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="tag2" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="tag1" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot validate things like that with XSD.

XML schema is not designed and not intended to check "intra-tag" relationships, e.g. "tag2 must be present if tag1's value is 'Y'" - just cannot be done, sorry.

If you need to check these kind of conditions, you'll have to look at [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) to do that.

Comment: I know a little bit about schematron .. sounds interesting .. but not much tools developed for it .. and even visual studio doesn't support it ...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this problem cannot be fixed using XSD. The reason is that XSD can only be used to define the structure (syntax) of XML-Files. What you would like to do is to couple the syntax to some semantic properties (some TAG must have a certain content to decide on the syntax of some TAGS nearby).

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible with XSD .. But by the way you can work around something like Infant-programmer if the requirement is bit comfortable as shown in her example ..