# XSD - validation

Tags: validation, attributes, xsd, element

My requirement is like, consider the following sample xml

```
<user key="username" value="Test"/>
<user key="age" value="27"/>
<user key="email" value="my@my.com"/>
```

In this case all the element having same name, same number of attributes and same attribute names too..

but i need to validate the **value** attribute according to **key**. For example here first key is username and its value is a string type, second key is age and its value must be a positive integer and third key is email so the value should be an email address.

is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across similar question many times,

here are my accepted answers to the following post:

[Restricting XML Elements Based on Another Element via XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126988/restricting-xml-elements-based-on-another-element-via-xsd/4141569#4141569)

[XSD: How to validate the XML file according to value of some tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879652/xsd-how-to-validate-the-xml-file-according-to-value-of-some-tag/1880030#1880030)

Answer (score 1):

You can translate your XML data with a XSL transformation into a form which can be validated with a XSD schema. This does not require any special custom tools.

Your input data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user key="username" value="Test"/>
    <user key="age" value="27"/>
    <user key="email" value="my@my.com"/>
</users>
```

Can be translated with the following transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/users">
        <users>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </users>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//user">
        <xsl:variable name="key" select="@key"/>
        <xsl:variable name="value" select="@value"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$key}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

into the following form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <username>Test</username>
    <age>27</age>
    <email>my@my.com</email>
</users>
```

And that can easily be validated with a standard XSD schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="users">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="age" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                <xs:element name="email">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:pattern value=".+@.+\.[^.]+"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSD doesn't support this kind of conditional validation. You need to use [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/).