# How to make child element attributes required based on parent element attribute in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

In below example of XSD what i want is if "Faron" element has the "TestMethod" attribute = 1 then the child element
faronsettings must have attribute "test1" and with value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Faron">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Application">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="FaronSettings">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="test1" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
              <xs:attribute name="test2" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
              <xs:attribute name="test3" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
              <xs:attribute name="test4" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="TestMethod" type="TestType" use="required" />
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="TestType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:minLength value="1" />
  <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
</xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSD: How to validate the XML file according to value of some tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879652/xsd-how-to-validate-the-xml-file-according-to-value-of-some-tag)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126988/restricting-xml-elements-based-on-another-element-via-xsd/4141569#4141569

Comment: ok so not possible with xsd ..is it possible by "Schematron"

Comment: yes it is possible! .Net and Java have good scope for Schematron extension!

Comment: can you help me with schematron

Comment: which is your host program? C#, VB, Java etc ..?

Comment: Does xsd validate broken xml like missing end tag of xml

Comment: No @Rusty, XSD does validates the data and hierarchy not syntax.. I mean before you load XML in host language it errors out .. it won't come upto validation!

Comment: Some schematron tutorials to begin! http://zvon.org/xxl/SchematronTutorial/General/contents.html

Comment: .net Schematron extension.. http://sourceforge.net/projects/schematron-net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XSD 1.1 with conditional type assignment and assertions.

Or use Schematron.

Or design your vocabulary so that the validity constraints can be expressed in terms of the element types without requiring appeals to attribute values.

You pay your money, you take your choice.

Comment: how/where to use XSD 1.1?? As per my knowledge it hasn't come to usage of developers yet! Can you please provide details if you are aware of its usage in any of the SDKs (Eclips, MSvisual studio etc)

Comment: Xerces J and Saxon-EE support XSD 1.1; many people find it convenient to use Oxygen (which bundles both of these) to manage XSD 1.1 validation.  If the SDK you use doesn't, you might consider lobbying the maintainers to move forward.

Comment: ah I use .net! so noway I am going to reach that star ! Neither I can upgrade my system! thanks for the info anyway!

Comment: I wouldn't be so pessimistic. [Saxonica](http://saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml) ships a .NET version of Saxon.